Generating empty output file
I wrote a code for generating an output file in my system in C++. The function is getting executed, but the only problem is that the output file generated is empty. Can anybody please tell me what I seemed to be doing wrong?
The input file is like this:
"1","02","Advance notification (confirmed)","Use for a complete record issued to confirm advance information approximately six months before publication; or for a complete record issued after that date and before information has been confirmed from the book-in-hand","0"

The code I wrote:
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::ifstream inputFile("/Users/a0p0ieu/Desktop/specRules/list.csv");
    std::ofstream outputFile("/Users/a0p0ieu/Desktop/specRules/output_spec.txt");
    std::string line;

    while (getline(inputFile, line)) {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        std::string col1, col2, col3;
        getline(iss, col1, ',');
        getline(iss, col2, ',');
        getline(iss, col3, ',');

        if (col1 == "1") {

            outputFile << "\"" << col2 << "\": {\n";
            outputFile << "    \"#" << col3 << "\": \"onix_productformcode.values[].value\"\n";
            outputFile << "},\n";
        }
    }

    inputFile.close();
    outputFile.close();
    return 0;
}

The output should be like this:
 {
    "2": {
      "#Advance notification (confirmed)": "onix_notificationtype.values[].value"
    }
  }

The same code is working on my friend's laptop.

Without seeing the input file, nobody can do much to help you.  [Edit] your question with a [mcve], but a debugger is probably your best option.

The value of col1 is "1", not just 1. You need if (col1 == "\"1\""). Or you should write parsing code that removes the quotes around the fields before you try to use it.

if (col1 == "1") -- Did you check what the actual value of col1 is when you read it in?  That is the minimal part of debugging that you should have done on your own.  Please  read why someone may/will downvote your question, all due to no debugging being done.

"The input file is like this:" -- Your question is about the output file, so why is an input file necessary? Or rather, how do you know the problem is not reading from the input file? If the problem is output, replace your loop with two lines: std::string col2 = "2"; outputFile << "\"" << col2 << "\": {\n"; and take the input file out of the picture. If the problem is input, output to the screen instead of to a file and replace your loop with two lines: getline(inputFile, line) std::cout << "I read: |" << line << "|\n"; (If it's neither of these, drop both files and debug more.)

@Barmar that should be posted as an answer

Have you tried running your code line-by-line in a debugger while monitoring the control flow and the values of all variables, in order to determine in which line your program stops behaving as intended? If you did not try this, then you may want to read this: What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems? You may also want to read this: How to debug small programs?

@StephenNewell How is that question similar? They didn't ask anything about a debugger. Of course, debugging is how experienced programmers solve problems like this, but by that logic you could use it as a duplicate for almost all newbie questions.

@Barmar - Automated text that comes comes when a question is marked as a dupe.  Because this can be solved by using a debugger.

@StephenNewell And I'm arguing that that's a bad duplicate, it's way too general.

@StephenNewell: I suggest that you read the following question on SO Meta: When should one duplicate a question to "What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?" It appears to be the community consensus that questions lacking debugging effort should not be marked as a duplicate of that question.

Since almost a day passed I assumed @Barmer is not intersted in posting an answer, and so did it myself based on the comment. The answer contains an addtional similar issue with the code lines for writing the output file.

There are 2 issues in your code, both related to enclosing values with quotes:

col1 in the input file contains "1" (i.e. the text contains quotes), not 1, and so when you compare the value in this line:
if (col1 == "1") {

It should be changed to:
if (col1 == "\"1\"") {  // note the escaped quotes in the strings content


Similarly col2 and col3 in the input file contain quoted values as well, and so when you write it to the output file you should actually not add additional enclosing quotes. Therefore these lines:
outputFile << "\"" << col2 << "\": {\n";
outputFile << "    \"#" << col3 << "\": \"onix_productformcode.values[].value\"\n";

Should be changed to:
outputFile << col2 << ": {\n";
outputFile << "    #" << col3 << ": \"onix_productformcode.values[].value\"\n";



With these 2 modifications the output file will contain what you expect:
"02": {
    #"Advance notification (confirmed)": "onix_productformcode.values[].value"
},


If the answer solves your problem @AnkitaPrasad, you could click '✔' to mark it as an accepted answer. You can also upvote any helpful answer(s) (voting and accepting is independant). See here: What should I do when someone answers my question?.
